# How to covert shortened html string into actual html link in label

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hey guys I am trying to print a list of responses from an API into labels and one issue I have is that the response (from JSON) is a string with a shortened link in it. When I put that string into a label the link is not recognized as a link the browser just think it is HTML so there is no underline or pointer. How can I solve this? I have already tried to HtmlEncode it and that did not help.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
lblResponse.InnerHtml += "<strong>created_at:</strong> " + item.created_at 
                    + "<strong>&nbsp text:</strong> " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.text) + "<br />";
```

Which returns this into the label. Though in my browser the shortened link is not recognized as a link. Advice?

created_at: Tue Apr 16 20:30:32 +0000 2013  text: Here is some social media news for the week... http://t.co/RR5DKvqUjd

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: A browser would never recognize plain text as a link. You need to wrap the `item.text` with a `<a href="item.text">item.text</a>`.

Comment: @JoeyGennari, OPs item text includes text with link not just link, this will create hyperlink for entire text not just url in text.

Comment: Missed that slight bit. Here are two resources for regex'ing the URLs: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html and http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the?522084f0.

Comment: My answer below will only highlight the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var date = "Tue Apr 16 20:30:32 +0000 2013";
var text = "Here is some social media news for the week... http://t.co/RR5DKvqUjd";
var textwithanchor = Regex.Replace(text, @"\(?\bhttp://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]", delegate(Match match)
    {
        return string.Format("<a href='{0}'>{0}</a>", match.ToString());
    });
var html = "<strong>created_at:</strong> " + date + "<strong>&nbsp text:</strong> " + textwithanchor + "<br />";
```

Regex gracefully borrowed from here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html but please take note of the caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
lblResponse.InnerHtml += "<strong>created_at:</strong> " + 
                         item.created_at + 
                         "<strong>&nbsp text:</strong> " + 
                         "<a href=\"" + item.text + "\"" + 
                         HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.text) + 
                         "</a><br />";
```